# How to split an array in half, and obtain two arrays

Tags: swift

I want to split an array in two half, and then assign each half of the original array into two different string. I cannot do the first part. I have this code for the splitting:

```
finalPlayers = players.shuffled()
let teams = finalPlayers.split()
test1 = teams.left
test2 = teams.right
firstTeam = test1.joined(separator: ", ")
secondTeam = test2.joined(separator: ", ")
```

The split() method is an extension of array:

```
extension Array {
    func split() -> (left: [Element], right: [Element]) {
        let ct = self.count
        let half = ct / 2
        let leftSplit = self[0 ..< half]
        let rightSplit = self[half ..< ct]
        return (left: Array(leftSplit), right: Array(rightSplit))
    }
}
```

The result of this code is just an half of the original array, and not both half, the two strings have the same value.

Expected behavior: if I have the array `people = ["Mark", "Jennifer", "Laura", "Paul"]` I want two string `firsString = "Mark, Jennifer` and `secondString = "Laura, Paul`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. `let players = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]; let subs = players.split(); print(subs.0); print(subs.1); print(subs.left); print(subs.right)` got me `["A", "B"]` & `["C", "D"]`. You can print `leftSplit` & `rightSplit` inside the method, but the values seems correct.

Comment: How are you printing the values? I was also unable to reproduce, like @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
let namesArray = ["Mark","Jennifer","Laura","Paul"]
let splittedArray = namesArray.devided()
let firstString = splittedArray.0.joined(separator: ", ")
let secondString = splittedArray.1.joined(separator: ", ")

print(firstString)
print(secondString)


extension Array {
    func devided() -> ([Element], [Element]) {
        let half = count / 2 + count % 2
        let head = self[0..<half]
        let tail = self[half..<count]

        return (Array(head), Array(tail))
    }
}


Output:
Mark, Jennifer
Laura, Paul
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you don't appear to actually have a problem.

Still, you may want to know about [`chunks`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md).

```swift
import Algorithms

public extension Collection {
  /// - Note: The first "half" will be longer by one element,
  /// if `count` is odd.
  var splitInHalf: ChunksOfCountCollection<Self> {
    let (halfCount, remainder) = count.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 2)
    return chunks(ofCount: halfCount + remainder)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide array into two array

```
    let people = ["Mark","Jennifer","Laura","Paul"];
    let middleIndex = ceil(Double(people.count/2));

    let firstHalf = people.dropFirst(Int(middleIndex))
    let secondHalf = people.dropLast(Int(firstHalf.count));

    print(firstHalf);  // ["Laura", "Paul"]
    print(secondHalf); // ["Mark", "Jennifer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func splitAndConcat(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    let length: Int = array.count
    let middleIndex: Int = length / 2
    
    let firstHalf = array[...(middleIndex - 1)]
    let secondHalf = array[middleIndex...]
    return [firstHalf.joined(separator: ", "), secondHalf.joined(separator: ", ")]
}
var names = ["Mark", "Jennifer", "Laura", "Paul"]
splitAndConcat(array: names) // ["Mark, Jennifer", "Laura, Paul, kartik"]
```